# going left: unrestricted / wrapping mouse tracking? in Flash?

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse

So, I'm shooting up dudes in [3D Game], and I can keep dragging my mouse to turn left round and round.

Is this possible in Flash?  Or have I misunderstood how the mouse is handled within [operating system] and then passed to the Flash Player?

Comment: I am confused.  Is the problem that you are dragging your mouse out of the swf?

Comment: ...yeah.  yeah it is. but even if you hold and click you can still get it to listen from outside of the player... I just thought, you know, someone might know.
maybe its a dumb question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I am aware, you cannot lock the mouse to the flash window for security reasons - if you could, imagine the flash ad nightmare!

However, Flash does track the mouse position if it does move outside of the window frame. You just have to watch out for clicking - you might have to remap fire to the CTRL key or something.